# How to insert data in a new line in excel gotten from C# whenever my .exe file is launched

Tags: c#, excel

I'm having an issue at the moment which I am trying to fix.
Trying to concatenate the values(Free space left in my SSD+ time of execution)after each scan I do (the scans are scheduled)and will be saved in a csv file.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace SSD
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

            foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
            {
                if (d.IsReady == true)
                {
                    var t = d.AvailableFreeSpace;
                    var AvailableFree = (t / Math.Pow(10, 9)) - 10;
                    var timeOnly = DateTime.Now;

                    FileStream ostrm;
                    StreamWriter writer;
                    TextWriter oldOut = Console.Out;
                    try
                    {
                        ostrm = new FileStream(@"path.csv", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                        writer = new StreamWriter(ostrm);
                        writer.Write(AvailableFree +","+ timeOnly);    

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Cannot open file.csv for writing");
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        return;
                    }
                    Console.SetOut(writer);
                    Console.SetOut(oldOut);
                    writer.Close();
                    ostrm.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine("Done");
               
                        while (true) { }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

May anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Kind regards

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Is there an error message? Are you not seeing the expected behaviour?

Comment: `while (true) { }` this looks like  a very tight unyielding loop.